# "USB Device Over Current Status. System will shut down in 15 seconds" after Installing software for new printer

Tags: usb, motherboard

So I got my Sister in law a used computer 6 months ago, but have since moved away, so cannot inspect in person.  The computer was working fine, and she got a new printer, a Canon Selphy CP1300.  She plugged it in (to the front USB), and installed the software from the disk.  After the restart, it started doing this.  The front USB ports are actually connected to a regular USB port that goes through the case and outside the back and plugs into a rear USB. I had never seen this before.

Anyways, I had her unplug everything, then plug in only power and DVI and it still comes up with this message.
It's an Asus P8P67 mobo with a i5-2500k.

Any thoughts or is the mobo hosed?

Comment: I would suggest trying in a another USB port in the back just to rule out the cable.

Comment: What do you mean? Even with all cables except power and DVI unplugged, she's still getting that message, and it shuts down.

Comment: The only logical troubleshooting to do was posted above. Try the same printer in another USB port directly, not with any extension cable: try in the same port without the cable, again, directly. Depending on the results it could be the USB port, the extension or both. If the synptom is the same try the printer in another computer. Same problem take it back to the store. If not then there's a problem in the original computer, probably a fried USB controller. *Any thoughts or is the mobo hosed?* **We don't know**, basic troubleshooting is required.

Comment: What I'm saying is that from powered off, and NO USB, including the extension or anything else, only power and DVI plugged in to the rear of the computer, she turns it on, and gets that message right away.  So I'm confused by your insistence to try the USB cable in another port?  What other _basic_ troubleshooting do you mean?  
She doesn't have access to another computer at the moment, but I'm not so concerned about the printer, just hopefully saving this PC.  
Thanks

Comment: My suggestion was based on the description of problem where you say it happened after connecting the printer but it persisted without it. Maybe there's a correlation but can be a coincidence or the new USB peripheral triggered an imminent/latent problem

Comment: If she has a restore point from before the printer was installed I would try that. If not, reinstalling Windows will do. In conclusion, there's a small chance of the problem being a weird software issue and this are the tests that can be done to rule that out or not.